# How do I hide the routes of a Bluemix web app so that it is only accessible from an API created using the API Management service?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to set up a publicly accessible API that will forward requests to apps with routes like [APP-NAME].eu-gb.mybluemix.net.

How do I ensure that the apps cannot be accessed directly?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible with IBM Bluemix, due to limitations in Cloud Foundry.

*All bound routes are accessible from the external network.*

If you want to have a private API, you have the following options.

- Add authentication to the REST API, managing the credentials as a user-provided service bound to all the apps. The API will be accessible externally but only by users with the credentials.
- Use an application service, like a message queue, to expose an internal RPC-style API. Applications can bind to the same service and it will only be accessible internally.